# VFS- Can't unlock return shipping label

Tags: shipping, vfs-global

So I went to my biometric appointment and I have all my paperwork set up. I bought my shipping label on the VFS website and now I am trying to unlock it through the confirmation email. I type in the correct password and it denies me. I have called the UK, I have emailed VFS but they take 2 days to respond. Has anyone had this issue? What did you do?

Comment: Try with an other browser, check if there is an other page (within the site) to make login. Note: for further details, you should write the country you are looking the visa (VFS manage visa for many (most?) countries).